# Cronjob - Stripping inodes % from command, sending in email

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I'm working on a cron script that sends an email when inodes hit 80%

```
#!/bin/bash
#
OUT=$(df -ih | sed -n '1!p') # remove first line because it's irrelevant - second line is important
RE="([0-9]+)%" # find first numerical item that has percentage sign with it
#
[[ "$OUT" =~ $RE ]]
#
PERCENT=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
#
if [[ $PERCENT > 80 ]]; then
    OUT2=$(./send_email.sh)
    echo "${OUT2}"
fi
```

It's coming along but not too well.

**Question**

How can I get the % of inode space used so I can send that number to myself in an email once it hits 80%? I'm open to suggestions that there is a better way to go about this.

Comment: The zeroth element of `BASH_REMATCH` is the bit of the string that matches the complete expression. If you want the first group, look at index 1. Also, `>` is not a numerical comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is cleaner:

```
[ -n "$(df --output=ipcent | awk -F '%' 'NR>1 && $1>80')" ] && echo "80% hit."
```

- `df --output=ipcent` outputs only the inodes percentage column.
- `awk -F '%' 'NR>1 && $1>80'` skips the header (with `NR>1`) and checks if the percentage is greater than 80%, printing the line if yes.

The pipeline output is checked by the `-n` test: If something was printed, than `echo` is issued. Substitute the `echo` by the mailing command.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the common GNU version of `df`, I suggest the following

```
#!/bin/bash
df -P | {
   full=()
   read header # discard the first line
   while read fs blocks used free cap mount
   do
       cap=${cap%?} # remove the last character
       [ $cap -ge 80 ] && full+=("$mount%$cap")
   done
   [ ${#full[@]} -ne 0 ] && send_email.sh "${full[@]}"
}
```

The `-P` ensures each line of output is one filesystem, otherwise `df` has an annoying quirk of wrapping lines to make the output look pretty.

The script assumes that the mount points don't have weird characters like whitespace in them.

The send_email.sh is given a list of filesystems which have 80% or more usage. The format is mountpoint, a percent sign and the amount. Adjust as needed.